# Lubuntu 18.04 with static addressing: have to continuously restart Network Manager

Tags: networking, lubuntu, network-manager

I recently set up static addressing on my desktop PC due to DHCP often having a DNS problem stopping me from getting online ([Intermittent Ubuntu family problem: Wifi itself connects, but cannot reach websites](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035705/intermittent-ubuntu-family-problem-wifi-itself-connects-but-cannot-reach-websi)). The link shows what my NetPlan YAML file for the static addressing looks like.

This at least allows me to get online, but there is an issue remaining: the connectivity is only available for a very short period before dropping out again. I find that the command `sudo service network-manager restart` quickly restores connectivity - but again for only a very short period.

So my online activity looks a bit like: play 1 game on lichess.org, restart the Network Manager, play the next game, restart the Network Manager again, and so on. Or: go to AskUbuntu and click the link to ask this question; write the question; and be sure to restart Network Manager immediately before posting the question.

Is this type of problem familiar to anyone?

Comment: Watch the logs as your problem occurs, with `journalctl --follow`.

Comment: Hi thanks for that, however, the logging stops at the line: `Jun 04 22:56:31 paul-office whoopsie[766]: [22:56:31] online`
At this point, I can get online and browse. Then after a short time, the ability to browse is lost, _but_, no additional entry has been added to the logging. So it's as if this problem is not detectable to `journalctl --follow`.

Comment: I've decided to replace Lubuntu on the affected desktop PC with Manjaro tonight. Somehow there must something unusual about my setup where Ubuntu family is prone to fail, so I will see if an altogether different distro simply works. Manjaro connectivity fine so far.

Comment: Manjaro was working yesterday evening, but today is day 2 of my Manjaro installation and I'm now unable to browse. I have formed the following opinion: if you're a TalkTalk customer using WiFi, out-of-the-box Linux distros may well hit DNS issues - I've been affected with Ubuntu, Lubuntu, Mint, and Manjaro.

Comment: Furthermore, the static address solution in the link in the original question is proving reliable on the laptop I'm typing this from. Therefore it seems I should next try full-blown Ubuntu on the desktop PC and give it a static address; hopefully that will be as reliable as this laptop. There is then just the minor point that Lubuntu doesn't seem to work correctly with the static addresses solution.